# Count from database and show output

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to count the user IDs in the database and show the total count as output, but I get an error. I use the following code:

//Controller Code

```
public function nsure(){
$users = DB::table('users')->count();
return view('nsure',compact(['users']));
}
```

//blade view code

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <span class="" style="color:black;  font-size: 14px">{{$user->id }}</span>
@endforeach
```

Comment: where you want to show count and where your getting error ?

Comment: `get an error`... always tell us exactly what the error is. It's easier than making people guess. Fortunately it's not complicated in this case, but it's not always so straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show all user IDs:

Controller

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Blade

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <span class="" style="color:black;  font-size: 14px">{{$user->id}}</span>
@endforeach
```

---

To show the total count of all users

Controller

```
$userCount = DB::table('users')->count();
```

Blade

```
<span class="" style="color:black;  font-size: 14px">{{$userCount}}</span>
```

Comment: It work when show all users but when i try to count total get below error.
"Undefined variable $userCount"

Comment: Make sure you add `$userCount` to your compact: `return view('nsure', compact('users', 'userCount'));`

Comment: now it works fine thanks. 
If i write 
$userCount = DB::select('select COUNT(id) as COUNT from users');  instead of $userCount = DB::table('users')->count();  why it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

`$users = DB::table('users')->count();`, `$users` is an integer, so you can not iterate it.

Comment: So what should i do for solve this ? my table name is users.

Comment: Do you want to output user information while outputting the count of users?

Comment: No i want only user total count as output no information needed.

Comment: @AbdullahALSamir then why did you write code which treats it like a list of users and tries to print the ID of each user? If you just want to echo the count, then just echo the count...